# Prove that: for an infinitely differentiable function f(x), the Composite Trapezoid Rule can be written the following formula .

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

Composite Trapezoid Rule
\begin{align*}
\int_{_{a}}^{^{b}}f(x)dx=\frac{h}{2}\left(y_{0}+y_{m}+2\sum\limits_{_{i=1}}^{m-1}y_{_{i}}\right)-\frac{(b-a)h^{2}}{12}f''(c)
\end{align*}
where $h=(b-a)/m$ and $c$ is between $a$ and $b$.
If $f$ is an infinitely differentiable function, 
**prove that**
\begin{align}
\int_{_{a}}^{^{b}}f(x)dx=\frac{h}{2}\left(y_{0}+y_{m}+2\sum\limits_{_{i=1}}^{m-1}y_{_{i}}\right)+c_{2}h^{2}+c_{4}h^{4}+c_{6}h^{6}+\cdot\cdot\cdot ,
\end{align}
where the $c_{i}$ depend only on higher derivatives of $f$ at $a$ and $b$, not on $h$. For example, $c_{2}=(f'(a)-f'(b))/12.$

Answer (score 0):

See [Error formula for Composite Trapezoidal Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2785873/115115), [Trapezoidal method, deriving error boundary.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2795439/115115) for the derivation of the first error term.

The general formula is due to the time symmetry of the quadrature method. First assume that the error has the form $c_1h+c_2h^2+c_3h^3+c_4h^4+...$, which you can do due to the infinite differentiability of $f$. Then consider the error for the quadrature of
$$
\int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx
$$
using the same method. The value and trapezium formula are the same, but the error is $-c_1h+c_2^2-c_3h^3+c_4h^4\mp...$. It follows that the odd-index coefficients all have to be zero.